# Differences between instances

Tags: java, jframe, instance

been messing around with JFrames a bit, and I noticed something:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Works, from what I can tell, the exact same as:

```
JFrame frame = JFrame.class.newInstance();
```

Are there any differences between these two ways when just using the Default instance with no parameters?

Thanks,

Legend

Comment: As Ernest wrote the two calls do (almost) exactly the same thing. But note the the second form is not considered best practice. `Class.newInstance()` should be used for reflection bases creation only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newInstance()` method in `java.lang.Class` constructs an instance of the class using the no-argument contructor -- so no, the two `JFrame`s would be identical.

The `Class.newInstance()` method becomes important when the `Class` object is created using a class name at runtime -- for example, a class name read from a file. Then you can say

```
String theClassName = ...;
Class clazz = Class.forName(theClassName);
Object o = clazz.newInstance();
```

Now you have an instance of a class whose name was not known when this code was compiled. If you know (by convention) that the named class implements some interface or extends some class, then you can cast the `Object` to that interface or class, and  use it that way. This is how, for example, servlet containers load servlets as described in configuration files, or web browsers load applets named in HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I have made an application similar to Codingbat and used that method. I just wanted to know any differences, thanks

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()

Answer (score 0):

[`newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) throws two checked exceptions that you have to deal with, and it prevents the compiler from telling you when you're doing something wrong (like trying to instantiate an abstract class).

And there's no such thing as a "Default instance."